# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

This crawling program is getting out of bounds exception
how to fix it?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
> 11, Size: 11  at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)  at
> Glowship_inv_battery.main(Glowship_inv_battery.java:68)

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.webscrap4j.WebScrap;
import com.webscrap4j.WebScrapException;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
  
public class letsbuybattery_inverterbattery 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> bl = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> cl = new ArrayList<String>();
        WebScrap ws = new WebScrap();
        
        ws.setUrl("http://letsbuybattery.com/inverters/");
        try
        {               
            ws.startWebScrap();
            
            al = ws.getSingleHTMLScriptData("<h5>", "</h5>");
            //mrp
            bl = ws.getSingleHTMLScriptData("<div class='clearfix'> ", "</div>");
            //selling price
            cl = ws.getSingleHTMLScriptData("<div class='item-price pull-left'>", "</div>");                
            
            HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/parthpatil/Documents/Abm Technologies/Crawl/letbuybattery_battery.xls"); 
             {

            // Create the Sheet
            HSSFSheet Sheet = workBook.createSheet("products");

            // Create the first row corresponding to the header
            Row header = Sheet.createRow(0);
            header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Product Name");
            header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Product Price");
            header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Product MRP");

            // Ensure that all the List have the same size otherwise throw an exception
            //  if (al.size() != bl.size() || al.size() != cl.size())
            //    throw new IllegalStateException("Some data is missing");

            // Iterate over all the list an create the rows of data
            for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++){
                // Create the current starting from 1 to al.size()
                HSSFRow row = Sheet.createRow((short) i + 1);
                // Cell of the Product Name
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(al.get(i));
                // Cell of the Product Price
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(cl.get(i));
                // Cell of the Product MRP
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(bl.get(i));
                
            }
            // Write the result into the file
            workBook.write(fos);
            
            for (String adata : al)
            {    
                System.out.println("the product are:- " + adata);    
            }

            for (String bdata : bl)
            {
                System.out.println("the MRp are:- " + bdata);    
            }

            for (String cdata : cl)
            {    
                System.out.println("the selling price is:- " + cdata);    
            }               
        }
             }catch (WebScrapException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure al, bl and cl are the same size????

Comment: your al, bl, cl must have different size.. debug your codes, or print the size before the loop.

Comment: The reason is that you're accessing 11th index of an array that has indexes from 0 to 10.

Comment: @balmy you shouldn’t modify people’s code in questions, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/525036. I rolled back this one but I see you are doing it a lot more, so I won’t start an edit war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a1,b1,c1 you have to make sure that b1,c1 and are atleast of same size or bigger than a1.size().adjust your logic accrodingly.means iteration statement should be on with minimum of values among the three arraylists.use something like below to find minimum size of among gives arraylists and use that value to start your loop.what error you are getting is produced in below code you will indexout of bound as clearly b1 and c1 are smaller than a1 and your i index will try to get b1.get(2),c2.get(2) which obviously does not have any value

```
    int d = c1.size() < (a1.size()< b1.size() ? a1.size() : b1.size()) ? c1.size() : ((a1.size() < b1.size()) ? a1.size() : b1.size());
```

```
public class TestArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        ArrayList<String> a1=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> b1=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> c1=new ArrayList<>();
        a1.add("a1");
        a1.add("a2");
        a1.add("a3");
        
        b1.add("b1");
        b1.add("b2");
        
        c1.add("c1");
        c1.add("c2");
        
        for(int j=0;j<a1.size();j++)
        {
            System.out.println("finding thestuuf from arralist to use in your excel cells"+">>>"+a1.get(j)+">>>"+b1.get(j)+">>>"+c1.get(j));
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help i got the point and changed my code , here page has many blank tags so had to skip bl and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explosion of the code happening:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++){
                // Create the current starting from 1 to al.size()
                HSSFRow row = Sheet.createRow((short) i + 1);
                // Cell of the Product Name
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(al.get(i));
                // Cell of the Product Price
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(cl.get(i));
                // Cell of the Product MRP
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(bl.get(i));
            }
```

you are looping with **al**'s size, but not checking the size of **bl** or **cl**...

Comment: al ,bl and cl are not of same size but wht matters is al for names , so i commented to some data missing exception

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11 
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653) 
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429) 
at Glowship_inv_battery.main(Glowship_inv_battery.java:68)
```

Let's translate it into plain English:

```
There was an Exception thrown because of accessing notexisting index which is 11 
    on an object which has size 11, so has indexes from 0 to 10.
It has occured on line 653 of ArrayList.java, in method rangeCheck,
    which was invoked from:
line 429 of ArrayList.java, in method get
    which was invoked from
line 68 of Glowship_inv_battery.java in method main
```

Possible solution. Put a breakpoint on line 68. of your `Glowship_inv_battery.java` file and debug. Your debugger surely have a possibility to lookup all values on runtime.